Fourier Series fit for Triangular pulse in Python
I have a triangular signal (or) more precisely a function that is triangular over a certain interval (0, 20) (I don't care how the output or the input signal is in other ranges). I would like to write the function in terms of cos and sin functions only. Or maybe just trying to find then Fourier series expansion.
So, I have created a function in Python doing this. This, is a symmetric triangular graph over (0, 20) with peak of 400 and minimum of 298.
def Real(t):
    if t<0:
        Ans = 298
    elif t<10:
        Ans = 10.2*t + 298
    elif t<20:
        Ans = 502-10.2*t
    else:
        Ans = 298
    return Ans

ts = np.linspace(0, 20, 100) # for generating plots
Rea = np.array([Real(t) for t in ts])

Then, I got to know about the np.fft.fft(array, n=N) idea (from chatGPT ofcourse). The theory I know is that, basically this command generates $Z_k$ for $ k = 0 \to N $ to satisfy the following equation.

So, I have found the equations and then created another function that would take these coefficients and evaluate the fourier series. And the result was horrible. Below was the code used (for reference)
# Generate time series data over the concerned interval
ts = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
Rea = np.array([Real(t) for t in ts])

N = 200 # Taking 200 fourier terms
Coeff = np.fft.fft(Rea, n=N)
def Four_Func(t):
    Ans = 0
    for n in range(len(Coeff)):
        Ans += Coeff[n] * np.exp(1j * n * t)
    return np.real(Ans)

Fourier = np.array([Four_Func(t) for t in ts])

The results were plotted as shown
plt.plot(ts, Rea, label='Real Signal in')
plt.plot(ts, Fourier, label='Fourier out')



where's the code to generate the plots?

Shouldn’t N be 100, not 200? You’ve only got 100 data points and appear to have ended up putting extra high-frequency components in. BTW, despite what ChatGPT has told you, that’s not how FFTs are worked out.

@lastchance Could you explain or cite about what do you mean by having 100 Data points yet adding extra high-frequency components. And also, I didn't know that this isn't how FFTs worked. Could you explain about that as well

@TinoD It has been added just now. Pls check (Although it doesn't affect anything)

Your discrete Fourier transform (as in numpy.fft.fft - see its documentation) is defined by

The inverse (accessible as numpy.fft.ifft) is defined by

Hence, if you want to write your series as straight multiples of exponentials

then you will need to scale the original fft; i.e. divide by N:

For a trigonometric series, note that the complex exponentials can be expanded (de Moivre's theorem) as

For a real function, cm and cN-m are complex conjugates. The series can be expanded as a pure cosine series if the original function (expanded periodically) is even and a pure sine series if the original function (expanded periodically) is odd. Otherwise, you will need sums of sines and cosines. In this case the periodic extension of your function is even and can be expanded as a cosine series.

You can also get such a series directly from numpy.fft.rfft
A final important point is that periodicity will automatically set f(t=20) equal to f(t=0). You should NOT send this point to the FFT calculator.
Here is code to get both exponential and cosine series for your function. Note that it is only guaranteed to fit at the original points from which you obtained the FFT. For a comment about improving this please see the edits at the bottom of this post.
You can increase NMAX to 100 or higher if you wish, but it will make the graph more congested (and obscure the fact that f(t) should not be explicitly defined at t=20).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

TMAX = 20                                                  # Pulse width
NMAX = 20                                                  # Number of data points (excluding the end, which assumes periodicity)

def RealFunction( t ):                                     # Vectorised version
    return 400 - 10.2 * np.abs( t - 10 )

# Generate time series data over the concerned interval
ts = np.linspace( 0, TMAX, NMAX, endpoint=False )          # IMPORTANT: periodicity will fix the last point - don't set it!
Rea = RealFunction( ts )

N = len( ts )                                              # This is the best you can do with this much data

Coeff = np.fft.fft( Rea )                                  # Formal discrete Fourier transform

# Coefficients for multiples of exponential functions
c = Coeff / N                                              # The 1/N comes strictly from the inverse DFT

# Coefficients for multiples of cosines
b = np.zeros( N//2 )
b[1:] = c[1:N//2] + c[-1:-N//2:-1]                         # Note that exp( ix) = cos(x) + i sin(x)
b[0] = c[0] + c[N//2] * np.cos( np.pi * N / 2 )            #      and  exp(-ix) = cos(x) - i sin(x)

def Exp_Func( t ) :
    Ans = 0
    for m in range( N ):
        Ans += c[m] * np.exp( 2.0 * np.pi * 1j * m * t / TMAX )
    return np.real( Ans )

def Cos_Func( t ) :
    Ans = 0
    for m in range( N//2 ):
        Ans += b[m] * np.cos( 2.0 * np.pi * m * t / TMAX )
    return np.real( Ans )

Exponential_Series = Exp_Func( ts )
Cosine_Series = Cos_Func( ts )

plt.plot( ts, Rea               , 'g-', label="Original" )
plt.plot( ts, Exponential_Series, 'rx', label="Exponential series" )
plt.plot( ts, Cosine_Series     , 'bo', markerfacecolor='none', markeredgecolor='b', label="Cosine series" )
plt.legend()
plt.show()


EDIT: It was raised by OP (KNVCSG) that the fit for the exponential series was not good for intermediate points, whereas the cosine series was much better. The reason for this is that, whereas c[N-m] is the complex conjugate of c[m], exp(2.pi.i.(N-m).t/Tmax) is NOT the complex conjugate of exp(2.pi.i.m.t/Tmax) unless t/Tmax is of the form n/N (i.e., one of the original points).
This is intimately related to the fact that, whilst the DISCRETE Fourier series contains modes going from 0 to N-1, the actual Fourier series in exponentials goes from -INFINITY to +INFINITY. In essence, we would like to "reposition" the second half of the DFT nodes as negative modes, effectively running from -N/2 to +N/2-1. A fudge to accomplish this is to amend the function Exp_func() to the following. When the graph is plotted at points with density 10*NMAX much better agreement is found.
def Exp_Func( t ) :
    Ans = 0
    for m in range( -N // 2, N // 2 ):
        Ans += c[(m+N)%N] * np.exp( 2.0 * np.pi * 1j * m * t / TMAX )
    return np.real( Ans )



Equal cosine terms will occur at the beginning and end of the sequence (m=1 goes with m=N-1, m=2 goes with m=N-2 etc.) These can simply be paired up by adding the c[m] and c[N-m] coefficients to produce the cosine series coefficients b[]. The sine terms should cancel for an even function (which is what you would get by a periodic extension of your triangular wave).

Not quite sure what your question is asking. However, from the mathematical definition of f_tilde, if f is a real function then c_m and c_(N-m) will be a complex conjugate pair. These coefficients will multiply cos(2.pi.m.n/N) and cos(2.pi.[N-m].n/N), which are equal from the periodicity and even-ness of the cosine function.

Actually, the function you construct using exponential series here is wrong. I don't know why. I found this out by plotting the values of function not only at the sample points that are chosen but also in between.
I have done this by creating a new array 'ts1' which has 10*NMAX and evaluated and plotted. The result was like this. Although surprisingly the function you constructed through cosines was correct and plot was like this

@KNVCSG, please see the edit at the end of my revised post. It explains why the function derived from the discrete Fourier transform is only guaranteed to fit at the original points from which you obtained it ... and also what you can do to get around that.

When I changed your code to be the following, I got more reasonable results:
    ts = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
    rea = np.array([Real(t) for t in ts])
    plt.plot(ts, rea, color='red')

    coeff = np.fft.fft(rea) / 100

    def Four_Func(t):
        Ans = 0
        for n in range(len(coeff)):
            Ans += coeff[n] * np.cos(2 * np.pi * n * t / 20)
        return np.real(Ans)

    Fourier = np.array([Four_Func(t) for t in ts])
    plt.plot(ts, Fourier, color='blue')
    plt.show()

The things you missed were:

I'm not sure why you added the n=200 to the call to fft.  That just adds another 100 "zeros" to the end of the array that is fft'ed.  I don/t think that's what you intended.

The output of an FFT needs to be scaled.  Hence I have to divide by 100 to get the coefficients back into range.  In your graph, the output of Four_Func was 200 time bigger than the output of your Rea function, so the latter got squashed down to a straight line.

Calculating the value of an FFT requires scaling the input to be in the range 0 to 2pi.  Hence my multiplying by 2π/20.  You chose to use exponents, which is fine, but your multiplier in that case should be 2π/20 j, not 1j.



N = number of coefficients (or) terms used in Fourier series right?? So, I thought the more I included the more accurate the function would be to the real signal. But, looks like it is not. Could you give me a reference so I can understand more about this??

I didn't know about this scaling thing. To what scale does the initial FFT correspond to? And I assume the reason you have divided it with 100 is because I used 100 sample points in time series??/

I have edited my code according to the recommended changes. And this is what I was getting this.
This is not enough accuracy for me. I have tried increasing no. of sample points but, no change.

The division by 100 is "normalization".  Its the number of points passed to the FFT. See "normalization" on this page: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft.

@lastchance's answer is better than mine..
